# Python 3 : Raising exceptions within excpetions

Tags: python, exception

Is the code below a bad practice? It works the way I want it, but couldn't find any other examples where an exception is raised within another exception. If it is a bad practice, what would be the ideal way to do this?

This code is in my low-level handler, and I want to have specific exceptions for codes HTTP 400/401 - as well as a generic exception for the other HTTP codes - in order to ease exception handling handling in my high-level wrapper(s).

Ideally there should be only one location where the HTTP codes are matched to a specific message or sub-exception.

```
class APIRequestError(APIError):
    def __init__(self, code=-1, message="N/A"):
        if code == 400:
            raise Exceptions.APIBadRequest(message)
        elif code == 401:
            raise Exceptions.APIAuthentication(message)
        elif code == 404:
            Exception.__init__(self, "HTTP 404 : API resource not found!")
        elif code == 500:
            Exception.__init__(self, "HTTP 500 : Server-side error!")
        else:
            Exception.__init__(self, f"Unhandled HTTP error ({code}).")

class APIBadRequest(APIRequestError):
    def __init__(self, message="N/A"):
        message_out = str(message)[:Exceptions.MSG_MAX]
        Exception.__init__(self, f"Bad API request : {message_out}")

class APIAuthentication(APIRequestError):
    def __init__(self, message="N/A"):
        message_out = str(message)[:Exceptions.MSG_MAX]
        Exception.__init__(self, f"Authentication error : {message_out}")
```

Comment: Vote to move this to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: How is it used? What problem does it solve? Is this just to generate the exceptions or will this do the wrapping (eventually) too?

Comment: It is called in my low-level API handlers. The high-level wrapper will be catching specific exceptions (e.g. 401 / APIAuthentication) to trigger specific actions (e.g. session refresh). The generic exceptions (e.g. 500 / APIRequestError) will be for user to deal with.

Comment: Beyond the "is it the best way to do that" question (t.b.h it might not be) I'm curious if it is a good practice at all or not.

Comment: @yorodm In it's current state, it's not welcome there.